Send azure service health logs to logs analytics workspace
I am trying to send Azure resource health, planned maintenance and service health logs to Logs analytics workspace for further processing directly without using event hub or intermediate services.
I have found that service health and resource health allow to create alert rules and action group which can invoke azure function/Logic app/Event hub/Webhook. But have not found an option to send the events to Logs analytics workspace directly. Is this even possible?
Thank you.

no need to send to la workspace. azure resource graph table ServiceHealthResources already have these record.

Did you try anthing?

@wenbo I am trying to send to LA because I want to have hall the logs at a single place and provide access to only that LA to other people.

I do agree with @wenbo that you can use Azure Resource Graphs and create alerts with it as below:

When you click on Open Query, you will be able to get and the run queries and check the logs of it as below:

To send Logs to Log Analytics Workspace you can use Azure Monitor and the use Diagnostics settings and then i think logs of full Azure Monitor to Workspace  can be sent and there you can check the logs:

